# Set the title of Custom Pages in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I've looking for info about how can I [modify the title](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Set-page-title) of an [ActiveAdmin Custom page](https://activeadmin.info/10-custom-pages.html), but nothing works. The solution I found only works for standard ActiveAdmin pages.

For example, my `Report` page

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "report" do
  controller do
    before_action { @page_title = "Generación de reportes" }
  end

  menu label: 'Generación de reportes'

  content do
    render partial: 'report'
  end
end
```

Shows the standard title, which is the same string with which it was registered.

[image]

**Is there a way I can customize the title, so I can put something like "Generación de reportes" for example?**

Comment: What are your versions of rails and activeadmin?

Comment: @JavierMenéndezRizo rails 5.2.2 and activeadmin 1.4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [your provided link](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Set-page-title), you have the following options to modify the title of a page:

```
content 'title': Proc.new {
  @page_title = 'Your title'
} do
 ...
end
```

or the other option, according the docs:

```
content title: "Your Title" do
 ...
end
```

According the docs, you have to see "*Image or link in the title bar of a custom page*" in the [same link](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Set-page-title)!

You using `before_action` when register a `controller`, but in the provided code, you are registering a `page`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that works! and you can directly provide title as value like this: 
`content title: title_value do
     your_code
  end`

Comment: At least in my case it worked with `content title: "title" do ... end`. The `Proc.new { ...` blah blah blah didn't work.